# How to testfor if a player is gliding with an elytra?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a map that requires a command to run if a player is using an gliding with an elytra. Are there any NBT tags or other commands that can be used to testfor gliding?

Answer (score 3):

The `FallFlying` tag will be 1 if the player (or any other mob) is flying with elytra. You can apply a label to the player based on that value for multiplayer-friendly detection:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=flying] remove flying
/scoreboard players tag @a add flying {FallFlying:1b}

/say Players that are flying: @a[tag=flying]
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can find out if the player ever flyed with the Elytra with this:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Flying stat.aviateOneCm
```

But that's not all. You can add a independent <kbd>Repeat</kbd> and <kbd>Always Active</kbd> command block to `/testfor` if all players that have flyed are not on the ground:

```
/execute @a[score_Flying_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ air
```

Then, to find out if this command returns false, use `/testforblock` again (`X`, `Y` and `Z` are the coordinates of the command block above) and put it in a <kbd>Repeat</kbd> and <kbd>Always Active</kbd> command block:

```
/testforblock X Y Z command_block -1 {SuccessCount:0}
```

Next to this one, place a <kbd>Chain</kbd> command block with a command to reset the scoreboard objective for all players:

```
/scoreboard players set @a Flying 0
```

Note: The above contraption is basically an implication gate - the output is activated only when input (command) 1 is activated, and command 2 not. You can replace command block #3 with an redstone implication gate.
Now, you've set up a elytra-flight detector (not compatible for multiplayer). To execute a command when a player is flying, use `/execute`:

```
/execute @a[score_Flying_min=1] ~ ~ ~ <command>
```

eg.

```
/execute @a[score_Flying_min=1] ~ ~ ~ say hello
```

Helpful links:

- [The Minecraft Wiki about Scoreboards](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard)
- [Arqade - How to make a command block chain](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/222140/how-to-make-a-command-block-chain)